# How to verify domains faster in Python?

Tags: python, dns, urllib, verify

Is there any way how to improve scripts verification speed? Or there is another (not a sw) solution?

I tried something like this (but its slow and useless):

```
import urllib
from socket import * 
import string, re

strings = string.ascii_lowercase
digits = string.digits

def validate(url):
    try:
        targetIP = gethostbyname(url)
        print url,' - Registered - ', targetIP
    except:
        print url," - Free"

def generate(url):

    for x in strings:      
        url_mod = "www."+ x + url
        validate(url_mod)

generate("atrion.com")
```

Comment: I don't think getting hostnames would work. Sometimes the domain may be registered by godaddy or whatever after the person who registered it didn't renew

Comment: For sure, I'm aware of that. I've written another function checking free domains from a function validate() through some whois servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your speed problem comes from looking up the domain in the DNS, not from Python.

I would try configuring my system to use a different DNS server, like the [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/).  Note that this is a system-level configuration, not a Python configuration.  You can find a link to configuration instructions on that page.

Note also that if you are making a *lot* of such queries, Google might interpret it as a denial-of-service attack and cut you off.  Just FYI.

Comment: Google DNS was also slow, but I tried openDNS server, that works perfect. Thanks for an advice.

Answer (score 2):

Since your program typically waits for network activity, you can probably get a speed-up by threading your program.

Having said that, if you can do this in another way, that would probably be preferrable.
What problem are you really trying to solve?
Do you just want to find out what domain names are free according to the example you provided or is there something else you are after?

Comment: Your idea sounds interesting, hope I'll be able to code it this way. The example I provided was only for demonstration. I'm trying to code a simple domain checker. The code is at first checking existance of the domain and next whether it's registered.